# How can I do a has_many relationship just using Ruby, i.e. not using Rails?

Tags: ruby

I don't mean how do I include ActiveRecord, but let me explain.

I want to have a `Game` with a `difficultyLevelID` and a `DifficultyLevel` Object.

In Rails and ActiveRecord (that's what I am familiar with) these would be tables and I would have the `has_many` and `belongs_to` methods and then I could just use the `difficultyLevelID` to get things, so difficulty level could be `Game.difficulty_level.name`

If I am just doing a Ruby program with no database and I want to use that relationship, i.e. I want `Game` to have an `ID` for difficulty level and the level `name` itself to be in a `difficulties` class, how do I do that (create, maintain and query the relationship) just with Ruby so that I can say get the game difficulty level name?

Comment: Why do you want the difficult level id in game? Rails has the ID in game so it can lookup in in the difficulty table. If you just have objects, set the difficulty object into game and get the id from the difficulty object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There was no answer in 20 hours so I've posted my own.**

```
class Soduko
  attr_accessor :name, :rows, :columns, :difficulty_level
  def initialize // will probably move to parameters as defaults.
    @rows= 9
    @columns= 9
    @name= 'My Soduko'
    @difficulty_level= 'Medium'
  end

  def initial_number_count
    DifficultyLevel.start_with_numbers('Medium')
  end

end

class DifficultyLevel

  def self.start_with_numbers(difficulty_level)
    case difficulty_level
      when 'Easy'
      then 30
      when 'Medium'
      then 20
      when 'Hard'
      then 10
      else 20
    end

  end

end
```

**and of course the tests:**

```
require './soduko'

describe Soduko, '.new' do

  before { @soduko_board  = Soduko.new }

  it "Should allow for a new Board with 9 rows (default) to be created" do
    @soduko_board.rows.should == 9
  end 

  it "Should allow for a new Board with 9 columns (default) to be created" do
    @soduko_board.columns.should == 9
  end 

  it "should have a default difficulty level of 'Medium'" do
    @soduko_board.difficulty_level.should == 'Medium'
  end 

  it "should have 10 initial numbers" do
    @soduko_board.initial_number_count.should == 20
  end 

end

describe DifficultyLevel, '.new' do

  it "should exist" do
    @difficulty_level = DifficultyLevel.new
  end

  # More to be added...

end
```

Comment: soduko? Did you mean "sudoku"? :)